# Check if a class exist within a group of selected elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of rows selected and I am now trying to determine whether or not they contain a specific class.

I have tried it with `hasClass` without success as well as with `find`:

```
var group = $('table').find('[data-group="group1"]');

//this doesn't work, it always enters in the condition
if(group.find('.active')){
    alert("Founded?");
    group.addClass('green');    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kAHyA/1/

I have also tried it with `if(group.find('.active').length)` but still not getting the correct result:

http://jsfiddle.net/kAHyA/3/

Comment: Why did `hasClass` not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with hasClass method
http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

```
if(group.hasClass('active')){
...
}
```

If you tried this :

```
if(group.hasClass('.active')){
...
}
```

It certainly won't work, note the difference with the "."

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
if(group.filter('.active').length)
```

Comment: It works well thanks! What is the difference between `find` and `filter`?

Comment: check the doc, it explains a lot

Comment: Well, as I can see, the main one is that `find` searches over the childs and `filter ` over all the elements on the selector. Am i wrong?

Comment: This is an overkill a simple seelctor is enough for this scenario i believe

Comment: @PSL It's overkill for the OP's example. But necessary if something "custom" needs to be done, like something unrelated to the jQuery object. It's not a bad option

Comment: I already have the elements saved in the variable to work with all of them in different ways. So I should not use a selector only for the active rows when I already have all the group of rows saved in memory.

Comment: @PSL Of course :) That's why there's several answers, all providing different ways to accomplish it. The "perfect" answer would tie all of these together and explain why each would be good. At the same time, a lot could have been skipped if the requirements/context were better explained

Answer (score 1):

Just want to check if the tr has class `active` and has the data attribute, so just a simple selector is enough.

```
var matches = $('table').find('.active[data-group="group1"]'); //This will give you all the trs with the attribute and class active.
if(matches.length > 0)
{
   alert('Found Match');
   matches.addClass('green');
}
```

if you just want to apply class directy just chain it through:

```
$('table').find('.active[data-group="group1"]').addClass('green');
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fYM6q/)

Comment: Why check for the length at all?

Comment: @Bergi He wants to alert somthing otherwise can just do an addClass there itself. Check my demo.

Comment: Why is your code different from what's in the fiddle? Your code here wouldn't work because `.length > 1` should be `0`. Your code in the fiddle makes sense and is better

Comment: @Ian aah thats a catch.. :) Fixed it.

Comment: Ideally no need to use any filter or hasClass etc at-least based on OPs question, just need to select tr which has the class as well as the attribute.

Comment: I already have the elements saved in the variable to work with all of them in different ways. So I should not use a selector only for the active rows when I already have all the group of rows saved in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this -

```
if(group.is('.active')){
    group.addClass('green');    
}
```

demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/kAHyA/6/

Comment: You *can*, but you *shouldn't* when there's `.hasClass()`

Comment: @Ian well the current jQuery "hasClass" implementation isn't super-smart; it could be somewhat faster if it'd use the native `matchesSelector()` (when available).

Comment: @Pointy But `.is()` doesn't even do that. For something like testing the `class`, I don't see why you'd want to use `.is()` which does a lot of extra processing (including parsing the string) when you can use a straightforward `.hasClass()` method that is quite fast as-is

Comment: @Ian I agree that it's not worth worrying about, and the additional overhead of `.is()` probably wastes the potential advantage of using native browser code to do the test. Before version 1.4, jQuery actually implemented `.hasClass()` with a call to `.is()`, but back then browser native support didn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with `.find()` is that it will always return a jQuery object, which like any other object (other than `null`) is truthy.

You want to check the length: `if( group.find(".active").length > 0)`

Comment: That's because it's looking for children with that class. If you want to know whether the element itself has the class, use `hasClass`...

Comment: `null` isn't an object, irrespective of what `typeof` tells you.